# Azure Cosmos DB is same as Firebase firestore or firebase real time databse?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any pub,flutter library available like firebase for Azure Cosmos DB for flutter?

Comment: are you have any update information for you question? I want to know which is better and good candidate for flutter App?

Answer (score 1):

Straight answer is No, Cosmosdb does not have the flexibility as Firebase to have the pub/sub implemented.

But there is an alternative which you can do by using multiple services by azure with SignalR + Cosmos DB please refer to this
[`sample`](https://github.com/ealsur/serverlessazurefriday)

Both of these use the [`Cosmos DB Change Feed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor), consuming it from [`Azure Functions`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/serverless-real-time-notifications-in-azure-using-azure-cosmosdb/).